# .ExecuteNonQuerry() error in SQLlite using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

searching in google, and in many posts here, but still I have not been able to find a solution for my program.
so the code:

```
      var str1 = flatComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var str2 = flatNumeric2.Value.ToString();
            var str3 = flatTextBox4.Text.ToString();
        var str4 = flatTextBox7.Text = ToString();
            SQLiteCommand SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE Produkte  SET Emri='"+ str1 +"', Sasia='" + str2 + "',Cmimi ='" + str3 + "', CmimiB='" +str4+"'  WHERE Emri='" + str1 + "'");

        try
        {
            connectionstring.Open();

            SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <--- Line 65 and the error

            connectionstring.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

This is the error I get.

[image: This is the problem I get]

how to fix this? I've tried many things over the time, and still looks like nothing can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to use a parameterized statement to avoid possible issues with apostrophes in C# string variables when they become part of the SQL query.

For example:

```
  SQLiteCommand SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE Produkte  SET Emri = @Emri, Sasia= @Sasia, Cmimi = @Cmimi, CmimiB = @CmimiB  WHERE Emri = @Emri");

SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emri", str1);
SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sasia", str2);
```

Or you can do:

```
SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Emri", str1));
```

And so on, for all parameters.

Comment: AdWithValue is not working. it shows an error. "SQLiteParameterCollection does not contain a definition for 'AdWithValue'

Comment: Can you try AddWithValue (two d's) ? Like this:
      SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emri", str1);

Comment: for SelectCommand.Parameters it has just Add. nothing else which contain Add or ad

Comment: Try this:
     SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Emri", str1));

Comment: it looks like it knows the sqliteParameter now, but str1 needs to be converted to DbType.

Comment: Try this:  
SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Emri", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = str1});